# WAMP not using virtual host domain for links

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I use WAMP 3.3.0 and Apache 2.4.54.2 and my virtual hosts have stopped working (it used to work, but it stopped working after I installed McAffee...I switched off the Firewall, but it didn't make a difference).

I did restart DNS (right-click WAMP tools->restart DNS). No change.

Here is my httpd-vhosts.conf (only one site...the others look similar):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mynaturephotography.localhost
DocumentRoot "d:/users/robert/onedrive/documents/my programming/wamp/www/non-ssl/mynaturephotography"
<Directory  "d:/users/robert/onedrive/documents/my programming/wamp/www/non-ssl/mynaturephotography/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

The problem seems to be that all links start with http://localhost/ instead of using the host name of the virtual host, in this case http://mynaturephotography.localhost/
From the access.log, I also noticed (maybe related?) that instead of using the entire path, files are fetched using only the part of the path starting from the home directory. Example:

> desktop-jo1uqtg - - [27/Aug/2023:20:33:23 +0700] "GET /MyNaturePhotography/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 302

The complete path would include the drive and the path to where the site files are located:

d:/users/robert/onedrive/documents/my programming/wamp/www/non-ssl